# Reinstate window snapping feature after reverting to Gnome Classic

Tags: 11.10, gnome, window

How do I get the window snapping feature working again after reverting to Gnome Classic on 11.10 like suggested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic/63315#63315)  to [How to revert to Gnome Classic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default Gnome Classic does not run compiz which has the windows snapping feature.

By choosing Applications - Other - Startup Applications you can add the following startup application `compiz --replace`:

[image]

You can control windows snapping via CCSM -

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

[image]

Comment: If I run compiz --replace, it reverts back to the Unity UI. Is there a way to get it to just start compiz?

Comment: very strange - the OP and myself have this working in Gnome-fallback... its worth a question!  Remember to add details of your graphics.  Also worth testing unticking the "unity plugin" option in ccsm to see if that helps.

Comment: Unchecking the unity plugin in ccsm worked. Thanks!