# Window snapping not working after uninstalled compiz?

Tags: compiz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reinstate window snapping feature after reverting to Gnome Classic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65801/reinstate-window-snapping-feature-after-reverting-to-gnome-classic)

I have uninstalled Compiz and expected that window snapping would start working again as per Unity default. But it does not. How do I reenable window snapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window snapping is enabled by a Compiz extension: the Grid Plugin. You cannot use window snapping without the Grid Plugin, and you cannot use the Grid Plugin without Compiz.

[image: CompizConfig screenshot showing plugin]

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/65810/18612) on a related question seems to indicate that Compiz is required in order to use window snapping in Unity.