# Gnome Session Fallback with Compiz -> Alt Click on Panel

Tags: 11.10, compiz, gnome-panel, gnome-fallback

As described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65801/reinstate-window-snapping-feature-after-reverting-to-gnome-classic) is is possible to enable the window snapping by activating Compiz. However this also disables the Alt+ ability on the panel. So after activating Compiz it is not possible anymore to add or remove something from/to the panel.

Is there a permanent workaround other then temporarily running metacity --replace when you want to modify the panel?

I would like to have both the window snapping and the Alt- ability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enabling Compiz changes the metacity <kbd>ALT</kbd>+Right click option for the gnome-classic panel to a slightly different key combination.

For Gnome-Classic with Compiz the key combination is <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+Right click where <kbd>Win</kbd> is the *windows* or *super* key on your keyboard.

Further information can be found in:

[How to revert to GNOME Classic Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)